# Does chrony have an IPC API to supply pps time for non standard GPS time source?

Tags: time, gps, gpsd, chrony

I have kind of an odd request. I have a GPS device that is non standard. It has a non standard communication interface. gpsd is not going to be able to digest it. Yet we want to use it as the primary (only) time source for a system. This GPS RCVR device has a C++ API we use to retrieve PPS based time and location information from the serial port. Yet, we would still like to use chrony server and clients to synchronize time in our embedded system containing lots of boards and SOMs.
We are looking into the possibility of setting up a chrony/ntp server using this non standard GPS device as its time source.
We would like to know if there are available IPC APIs (whether socket, message queue, or shared memory) to feed a chrony server time information that it would use to set system time?

Any thoughts or help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks
-Andrew